# Laravel can't create model with Model::create() and $model->save()

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I want to seed the `hero` table, but I get the following error.

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::insertGetId()
>   must be of the type array, object given, called in
>
> E:\xampp\htdocs\cyberpunk\vendor\laravel\framework\
>   src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder.php on line 1350.
>
> Exception trace:
>    Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::insertGetId(Object(App\Hero),
>   "id") 
>   ...vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder.php:1350

**Seeder**

```php
User::find(1)->hero()->create([
    'name' => $faker->userName,
    'level' => $faker->numberBetween(1, 99),
    'strength' => $faker->numberBetween(1, 20),
    'vitality' => $faker->numberBetween(1, 20),
    'stamina' => $faker->numberBetween(1, 20),
    'agility' => $faker->numberBetween(1, 20),
    'perception' => $faker->numberBetween(1, 20),
    'luck' => $faker->numberBetween(1, 20),
]);
```

I have a one-to-one relation between `User` and `Hero`. I want to create a new `hero` via the `user` model. This way also causes the same error.

```php
$hero = new Hero;
$hero->user_id = 1;
...
$hero->save();
```

**User**

```php
class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public $appends = ['hashid'];

    public function hero()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Hero::class);
    }
}
```

**Hero Model**

```php
class Hero extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['level'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us a Users and Heroes model classes?

Comment: Of course, i have edited post.

Comment: Can you post the entire Seeder file

Comment: try adding 'user_id' (and all others fields) to the fillable property in Hero Model : protected $fillable =[ 'user_id', 'level', ...];

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `$fillable` config. Try adding your fields to the `$fillable`:

```
class Hero extends Model {

    protected $fillable = ['level', 'client_id', ... ]; // <-- your allowed fields

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Now, keep in mind that this will need to be applied for the majority of your fields. An alternative is to make use of the opposite, the `$guarded` attribute. You list there the fields that you want to protect against mass-assignment:

```
class Hero extends Model {

    protected $guarded = []; // <-- your protected fields go here

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Check the [related section](https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/eloquent#mass-assignment) of the documentation.